# Problem about pcl library in ROS

Tags: ros, kinect, pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. i'm trying to use this library  <pcl/io/openni_grabber.h> (i have istalled the pcl library for Ubuntu from this link http://pointclouds.org/downloads/linux.html) in my script using ROS (version electric for Ubuntu 11.10) , but although i have included it in my script, when i make the file it doesn't work.
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31621/problem-about-pcl-library-in-ros/) by [Roberta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2063/roberta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-04-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-04-11**:
More info required, like what dd u do, what is the error displayed, your environment, OS, ROS version and PCL version. Only then people will be able to answer the question.

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-04-11**:
Still not clear as to what are you trying to do. Whats your script? Make file doesn't work, means any error? What are you trying to make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For ROS Electric you have to use the PCL library that comes with ROS ... you can't use the standalone library from Pointclouds.org. ROS uses an older version of PCL. Take a look at [joq's answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/30944/pcl-library-version-in-ros) to a similar question.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1